# What were the facts seen by the man born blind narrated in John 9 that the Jews did not see?

Tags: jesus, jews

> Jesus said, "For judgment I have come into this world, so that those who do not see may gain their sight, and the ones who see may become blind."  (Jn. 9:39 NET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background of the account is John 9:1-34. Jesus and His disciples encountered a man blind from birth, and the disciples asked Jesus that this man born blind was due to his sin or his parents' sin. Jesus replied neither the cases, but it happened so that the works of God might be displayed in him. Then we see a famous quote

> 5 While I am in the world, **I am the light of the world.**” (John 9:5 NIV)

So the works of God displayed in this blind man and his eyes opened. The Pharisees bewildered the case and investigated to get his testimonial. The dialogue between the Pharisees and the man was given in John 9:15-34. The Pharisees opened the dialogue with a poor start, blind by their bias, they turned the investigation into an interrogation.

> 16 Some of the Pharisees said, “This man is not from God, for he does not keep the Sabbath.” (John 9:16 NIV)

Now what did the blind man see? He saw the light of the world (John 9:5), which the Pharisees didn't see even their eyes weren't blind.

**For sin cloud our eyes to see the light of the world, i.e. our Lord.**